# How do I properly extract a number that starts and ends with the same number

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

I'm trying to learn how to extract all the numbers from a string where the number starts with a random digit that's between 0 - 9 and then ends with the same one, but if there is another one of that digit before the next letter appears, it should include that one too.

Let me show you an example.
Take this string for instance
`12346171par827here727next8number5052car`
My program would then extract `12346171`, `727`,`505`

And what I have so far is this, which obviously isn't doing what it's suppose to, but I can't figure out a good algorithm.

How do I properly extract the numbers?

```
string input = "12346171par827here727next8number5052car";

var charArray = input.ToArray();
int pos = 0;

var firstNum = 0;
var secondNum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < charArray.Length; i++)
{
    if (char.IsDigit(charArray[i]))
    {
        firstNum = charArray[i];

        for (int j = i; j < charArray.Length; j++)
        {
            if (char.IsDigit(charArray[j]) && charArray[j] == firstNum)
            {
                secondNum = charArray[j];
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand the output here , why doesn't the result include `123461` and `171`. Is this a mistake, or is this the actual behavior you want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your rules are properly defined. You could do this *O(n)* fairly efficiently with a good old fashioned *for loop*

**Given**

```
public static IEnumerable<string> Get(string input)
{
    int last = -1, first = -1;
    for (var index = 0; index < input.Length; index++)
        if (!char.IsDigit(input[index]))
        {
            if (last > 1)
                yield return input.Substring(first, last - first + 1);
            first = last = -1;
        }
        else if (first == -1)
            first = index;
        else if (input[first] == input[index])
            last = index;
    if (last > 1)
        yield return input.Substring(first, last - first + 1);
}
```

**Usage**

```
var input = "12346171par827here727next8number5052car";
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", Get(input)));
```

**Output**

```
12346171, 727, 505
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/apqA7v)

Answer (score 3):

An easy way to achieve that would be to use [Regular Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference). You may use the following regex pattern:

```
([0-9])[0-9]*\1
```

**[Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5B0-9%5D%29%5B0-9%5D*%5C1&i=12346171par827here727next8number5052car)**.

**Details:**

```
([0-9])    # Matches a single digit and put it in group #1.
[0-9]*     # Matches zero or more digits.
\1         # Matches the same string that was captured in group #1.
```

Here's a full example:

```
string input = "12346171par827here727next8number5052car";

string pattern = @"([0-9])[0-9]*\1";
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

**Output:**

```
12346171
727
505
```

Note that the pattern above will match "505" out of "6505". If you want to prevent that by making sure that the repeated digit is at the beginning of the number, you may use a negative [Lookbehind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/backtracking-in-regular-expressions#lookbehind-assertions). In that case, the pattern would be:

```
(?<![0-9])([0-9])[0-9]*\1
```

**[Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!%5B0-9%5D%29%28%5B0-9%5D%29%5B0-9%5D*%5C1&i=12346171par827here727next8number5052car%0D%0A6505)**.